# catch exception inside new initialized blocked of an object in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Here I am unbale to catch the exception inside the simplified initialized block of an object created using new keyword.

```
Test test1 = new Test() { };
```

I tried below code but unbale to catch the exceptions

```
Test test1 = new Test()
{
 try
 {
  
 }
 catch()
 {
 
 }
};
```

Comment: You're confusing an object initializer with a block of code.  They are not the same thing.  Did you mean to *wrap* the statement in a try/catch?

Comment: Thanks David for your quick response. 
Yes I want to catch exception occurred inside object initializer block.

Comment: You need to catch the exception inside your property setters in the object or, as mentioned, wrap the whole statement in a try catch.  Object initializers can't run code, only initialize properties.

Answer (score 2):

The `{ }` here is an [*object initializer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer), not a block of code:

```
Test test1 = new Test() { };
```

You can't just put any statements you like in an object initializer.  It's just syntax for initializing properties on the newly created object.  For example:

```
Test test1 = new Test() { SomeProperty = "test" };
```

It's *semantically similar* (similar enough in nearly all cases) to this:

```
Test test1 = new Test();
test1.SomeProperty = "test";
```

If you want to catch an exception which occurs during the creation of the object, *wrap* it in a try/catch.  For example:

```
try
{
    Test test1 = new Test() { SomeProperty = "test" };
    // use test1 for something...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

Alternatively, if the scope of `test1` needs to be outside of the try/catch, you can *declare* it first:

```
Test test1 = null;
try
{
    test1 = new Test() { SomeProperty = "test" };
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception
}
// if test1 is not null, use it for something...
```

If, on the other hand, you're looking to handle exceptions more specifically within the setters for any given property, you'd either handle them within that setter or you'd avoid the object initializer syntax and individually set the properties, wrapping relevant ones in a try/catch as needed for your logic.

Comment: "It's semantically similar (similar enough in nearly all cases) to this".  Personally, I wouldn't consider it "nearly all" anymore, but maybe that's just me.  Since the addition of property init'ers and required properties, object initializers have gained rather extreme significance.  Still, I'm upvoting.